# Disable focused when hovering over other navbar items

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, navbar

I am strugglich with an issue, that my Navbar items get underline animation, when hovering over. Once clicked, animation stays there. However, if I hover over the neighbor navbar item, the two lines will appear next to each other, looking like one long line. [image]

So here produkt is focused and preise is hovered. I wish, that when I hover over preise, the product gets unfocused. However, if I don't select preise, focus "returns back" to the product. Code below

```
.undeline:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 3px;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: #52ae49;
    border-radius:3px;
    margin-top: -10px;
    visibility: hidden;
    transform: scaleX(0);
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
}


.undeline:hover:before {
    visibility: visible;
    display: block;
    transform: scaleX(1);
}

.undeline:focus:before  {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 3px;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: #52ae49;
    border-radius:3px;
    margin-top: -10px;
    visibility: visible;
    display: block;
    transform: scaleX(1);
}
```

I assume, I will have to manage this with JavaScript and use .forEach. I tried this

```
    function mouseOver() {
    $(".underline").each(function() {
    $(this).blur('focus');
    });
}

function mouseOut() {
    $("underline").each(function() {
    $(this).addClass('focus');
    });
    }
```

But with no success.

Comment: Please provide your HTML and a verifiable example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here when you mean focus, i suppose you are talking about when you click the link. As focus is more suitable for html elements like input fields.

Please run the code snippet below to see it in action.

```js
$('.nav li').on('click', function() {
  var $link = $(this);
  if (!$link.hasClass('selected')) {
    $link.addClass('selected');
    $link.siblings().removeClass('selected');
    $link.siblings().removeClass('dimmed');
  }
});

$('.nav li').hover(
  // hover in handler
  function() {
    $(this).siblings('.selected').each(function() {
     if (!$(this).hasClass('dimmed')) {
      $(this).addClass('dimmed');
     }
    });
  },
  // hover out handler
  function() {
    $(this).siblings('.selected').each(function() {
     $(this).removeClass('dimmed');
    });
  });
```

```css
.nav {
  display: flex;
}

.nav li {
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  cursor: pointer;
}

li.selected.dimmed:before,
li:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 3px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: #52ae49;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin-top: -10px;
  visibility: hidden;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
}

li:hover:before {
  visibility: visible;
  display: block;
  transform: scaleX(1);
}

li.selected:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 3px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: #52ae49;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin-top: -10px;
  visibility: visible;
  display: block;
  transform: scaleX(1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="nav">
  <li>produkt</li>
  <li>preise</li>
</div>
```

Comment: You basically saved my life, I am so greatful! I found an easier way though to solve it with excluding classes, if I may say like this: 
.navbar-start:hover .undeline:focus:before {
    transform: scaleX(0);
      transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
.navbar-start:hover .undeline:hover:before {
    visibility: visible !important;
    display: block;
    transform: scaleX(1);
}

It also worked, but problem was, that I couldn't add the .undeline class on scrolling or remove. as it had these pseude calsses, which were hard to select. So your solution solved scrolling problem. Thanks!

Comment: I am glad it was helpful to you :)